# Unit testing for java program

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, junit

I have a Java program which reads the contents of a file containing a list of numbers, picks out numbers which have been duplicated and writes them to the console.cant figure out where to put them or what they should look like. 
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

```
public class ReadAFile {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String list[] = new String[];

        FileInputStream fstream=new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/testfile.txt");
    // Use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text.
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        String str,str1;
        int i=0;
        while((str=br.readLine())!=null){
            i++;
            str1=Integer.toString(i);
            if(lines.containsValue(str)){
                System.out.println(str);
        }
        in.close();

}
}
```

Comment: you should read some tutorials first

Answer (score 2):

you need to think of a test-case, write a test-class, and put it under /src/test/java directory.
Then you need to write some methods inside test-class(separate method for a testcase is common way), annotate that method with @Test annotation and run maven

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this [tutorial here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html#easymock)!, it very thorough providing details about how to run Unit tests in Eclipse and making use of EasyMock.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests in a maven project usually are located in a separated source folder /source/test/java. Maven automatically executes all tests found at this location.

To test your class you would have to refactor it so you can set the path to the input file to an test file that you may place in /source/test/resources for instance. At least if you want to write an integration test that verifies the reading of the input file.

The processing logic that identifies and prints duplicated entries may be tested via a "real" unit test that somehow mocks the BufferedReader and provides some test data without reading it from a file. Here easymock may be one library you can use.

To simplify the testing of your class your may put all your logic in a non-static method and call it from your main method by creating an instance of the class itself.

```
public class ReadAFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReadAFile instance = new ReadAFile();
    instance.readAFile(args[0]);
  }

  public void readAFile(String fileToRead) {
    HashMap<String,String> lines=new HashMap<String,String>();
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First step would be to organize your code in units so that each unit can be tested.  In Java world, this unit would be a method in your class. So first step, write your code in a method other than 'main'.

Next, you write a program which tests the method you wrote.  Basic structure of such a program would be

1) Do anything which is required to run the method under test.
2) Run the method
3) Observe the output to verify if it produced correct results.

JUnit is a Java library which makes it easy for your write such tests by providing some pre-canned methods.

You have the basics now, rest, as they say, can be googled.

Answer (score 1):

Really straightforward tutorial is here [from mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-run-unit-test-with-maven/) it worked really well for me when I started with unit tests. Also some mocking for the Input Output manipulation will be handy.

Answer (score 0):

As you already has included junit in your project, you have to think in the following structure for unit testing.

[image]

You will have for each class you want to test, a correlative class to test it, so `MathTest` will unit test `Math` class

Then, imagine you modify your code to have 2 methods, one for read a file, one to parse the InputStream and one to showResults.

Here is an Interface I would use, but take it just to know the method declaration.

```
public interface MyCodeToBeTested {

    List<String> parseFile(final String path);

    void processLines(List<String>);
}
```

Imagine you implement this interface with a class named `ImplementedClass`.

So you can have a Junit class which test each of the methods looking for fails.

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Tester {

    @Test
    public void testReadFile() {
        ImplementedClass myclass = new ImplementedClass();
        List<String> lines = myclass.parseFile("mytestfile1.txt");
        Assert.assertEquals(3, lines.size());
        Assert.assertEquals("this is the first line of the file", lines.get(0));
    }

}
```

With this test you check that parsing a file works fine, one time you are confident with your read file though unit testing, you can move to test the processLines method without taking care of the file.

```
    @Test
    public void testProcess() {
        ImplementedClass myclass = new ImplementedClass();
        List<String> lines = initializeLines();//initialize your lines
        myclass.processLines(lines);
        //Assert here myclass results
    }
```